# Strange behavior of TimePickerDialog when press POSITIVE BUTTON

Tags: android

I'm working with an Alarm Application, I want to show a TimePickerDialog with two button (Ok and Cancel) I use this code to get the current time when use click on OK button:

Code to show dialog:

```
    final TimePickerDialog pic = new TimePickerDialog(
        TimerSettingsActivity.this,
        android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog_NoActionBar,
        timePickerCallback, hour, minute, true);
pic.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.dialog_time_title));
pic.setButton(DatePickerDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK",
        new DatePickerDialog.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
                    mIsClickOkButton = true;
            }
        });
pic.setButton(DatePickerDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel",
        new DatePickerDialog.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE) {
                    mIsClickOkButton = false;
                }
            }
        });
pic.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    }
});
pic.show();
```

And here is the Set time listener:

```
OnTimeSetListener timePickerCallback = new OnTimeSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        if (mIsClickOkButton) {
            // Save time to pref
            String pref_time = String.valueOf(hourOfDay) + ","
                    + String.valueOf(minute);
            mEditor.putString(Common.PREFS_TIME, pref_time);
            mEditor.commit();
            mTxtTime.setText(Common.createTimeStringToShow(hourOfDay,
                    minute));
        }
    }
};
```

I use the LG Optimus G to test, it's run OK, the behavior of this dismiss is OK button pressed => onTimeSet

But when I've release this app for my customer (Samsung devices), when press OK button, it's not run correctly. Any ideas?

Thank you!